# Spring batch job csv file read recover from the line where it failed

Tags: spring, csv, spring-batch

The reader looks like this,

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

    <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/input/report.csv" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="id,impressions" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

What I want to achieve is, if while reading the CSV file, the reader/job fails, then the next scheduled jobinstance should start the reader from the line it failed in last jobexecution. I can keep track of lines processed by a counter in the CustomProcessor process() function.

But any idea how to read the csv file from the last execution's failed state?

I want to manually launch/restart the failed job. Should I implement SkipPolicy as described here http://thisisurl.com/spring-batch-skip-and-retry?

(CSV file can be a big DB as well, but for now I am testing this scenario on CSV file)

Comment: this is a built-in feature of SB; it is called restartability.

Comment: @bellabax Will just putting restartable="true" in the job will achieve it?

Comment: Not necessary, `restartable="true"` is the default

Comment: ok. but what if you want to restart it manually? as I want to administer failures, and launch afterwards manually again. One more thing, if there are 10 rows in my csv file. The read/write counters are 10 but commit is 11. why is it so?

Comment: inconsistent commit count explained. no worries http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/62488-inconsistent-commitcount

Answer (score 1):

## If your application fails, you can use folowing:

> But any idea how to read the csv file from the last execution's failed state?

Add it to [jobParameters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/domain.html#domainJobParameters) they saved in batch table **batch_job_execution_params**.

At application start up find incomplete jobs in **batch_job_execution** and restart in manualy.

> I want to manually launch/restart the failed job. Should I implement SkipPolicy as described here http://thisisurl.com/spring-batch-skip-and-retry?

I think this is not necessary, for [restartability](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#restartability).

## If you want restart some lines in your csv, just use RetryPolicy:

```
    <batch:step id="processing-step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="csv_reader"
                         processor="csv_processor"
                         writer="csv_writer"
                         commit-interval="5">
                <batch:retry-policy>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.AlwaysRetryPolicy" scope="step"/>
                </batch:retry-policy>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Spring Batch automatically handle failed chunks (chunks, in which throws an exception). [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#retryLogic).